# Splash screen should check data from database

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data, mapkit

hi i am creating an map application ,
initially when i click on the application icon on iphone a Splash screen showing application logo and a loading bar should be shown.

Expected Process:
Screen should achieve following objectives of initialization

1.Initialization of Synchronization Web Service
2.Create or Open available database on the device and keep the referece in the memory for quicker calling.
3.Validation of available UserInformation Record in database
4.Build up a Weather Map which should hold all 37 types of weather available for easy future reference
On each processing step progress bar should grow/fill with 25%

How could this be possible.Please anybody help me in achieving this tasks

Comment: It is bad mobile user interface design to make the user wait for several seconds while the app launches. If it takes more than 5 seconds for a non-game app to launch to the point that the user can begin to do something, users will perceive the app to be slow or hung. Try the walking-thumb test: while walking with your app, launch and manipulate the app using only the thumb of one hand. The perception of acceptable launch time is much different when the app is used on the move than it is when people are sitting down with a desktop/laptop.

Comment: If you actually have long launch times, put the time consuming task on a background thread. That will let the interface come up and let the user orientate themselves to the interface and begin to use the app. This may take 5 seconds or more so you can stretch your effective launch window to 10-15 seconds without the user realizing it. The app will feel fast and responsive.

Comment: All the above would be especially true of a Weather app. People want weather answers fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The splash screen is just an image that should be called `default.png`. It will display during the launch of you app.

To realize what you want you have to define the first view controller with the same background and a UIProgress and do your sync and other processes.

When initialization is done you have to display your "real" first view controller

Comment: where should i set the default.png

Comment: the picture should simply be added in you project. If you are using xcode 4, you can select the project and in target summary there is a place for that

Comment: thanks i have got the default.png but it stays only for a second i want that it should remain for atleast 4-5 seconds. How to do that

Comment: `default.png` will be display during the **app initialisation** but not during **your initialisation**. You have to define your first controller (used only for sync) with the same background as default.png and do your sync processes. Then when **your initialisation** is done your display your first "real" controller

Answer (score 0):

When user launch the application you could show a splash screen for 1 or 2 second after that you could show the progress (status) of your application using text msg.

for example "Initialization of Synchronization Service" ,"Storing to data base", "Loading map" .

The above text msg. is just a reference,you could have more descriptive text to show on screen along with progress bar.